# How to return a property of an object if its other property is known?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have array of objects with unique names:

```
let arr = [
  {
    'name':'B',
    'id': 1
  },
  {
    'name': 'c',
    'id': 12
    },
  {
    'name': 'a',
    'id': 13
  }
]
```

How can I get `id` if I know the `name`. For example I have `B` and it need to return `1` ?

My solution :

```
const foo = (arr, name) => arr.filter(el => el.name === name)[0].id

foo(arr, 'B') // 1
```

Hope there is a better solution to this problem

Comment: If `name` is unique, consider using [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) instead. `filter()` will always check *all* elements in the array, whereas `find()` will stop on the first `true` result. Note, with `find()` you will not need `[0]`, as it returns the found item (or `undefined` if nothing is found).

Comment: Use `.find()` instead.

Comment: Thanks for fast answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Array.prototype.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) is fine for few lookups if you don't mind that it's not supported in IE, and that it can result in error if the item is not found. For multiple lookups, I recommend making a lookup object :

```js
const arr = [ { name:'B', id: 1 }, { name: 'c', id: 12 }, { name: 'a', id: 13 } ]

const obj = arr.reduce((o, v) => (o[v.name] = v.id, o), {})

console.log( obj['B'] )   // 1
console.log( obj['A'] )   // undefined
```

---

If by any chance the data is from `JSON.parse` :

```js
const obj = {}, json = '[{"name":"B","id":1},{"name":"c","id":12},{"name":"a","id":13}]'

JSON.parse(json, (k, v) => v.name ? (obj[v.name] = v.id) : v)

console.log( obj['B'] )   // 1
console.log( obj['A'] )   // undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) instead of [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), because `.find()` returns only the *first* matching element of the array - `.filter()` returns *all* matching elements. Your code should look like this:

```
const foo = (arr, name) => arr.find(el => el.name == name).id;
```

Working snippet:

```js
let arr = [
  {
    'name': 'B',
    'id': 1
  },
  {
    'name': 'c',
    'id': 12
  },
  {
    'name': 'a',
    'id': 13
  }
]

const foo = (arr, name) => arr.find(el => el.name == name).id;

var theID = foo(arr, 'B');

console.log(theID);
```

Comment: @Slai I've fixed it now.